# Jbpm process model link directly to DMN (decision table)

Tags: decision-tree, jbpm

I have started using jbpm suite and would like to ask, is there a way I can link or refer my business rule task or decision task directly to DMN file ? (or decision tree) rather going through facts, rules or action (Drools). If yes, pls provide any example or reference url

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Can you show a code example of what you're currently doing that isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to link DMN in the BPMN editor for the Business Rule Task, you can select "DMN" instead of DRL.

Then in the Data I/O as input you need to supply namespace+name of the DMN model you want to evaluate, along with the required Input Data, and mapping of the required Decision which are meant to be used as output.

Example:

[image]

1. model namespace
2. model name
3. required Input Data
4. required Decision result to be used as output.

The following presentation contains a comprehensive demo of BPMN and DMN integration, if that might be of help: https://youtu.be/C0u3ZDiH3ek?t=15m2s